# Give an example of a finite extension of fields that is neither separable nor normal.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The title says it all. This is not homework. Haven't made much progress - I know that with $K=F_2(t)$, $L=K(\sqrt t)$ (i.e. adjoining the square root of $t$ to the function field with coefficients in the finite field on two elements), $L/K$ is not a separable extension. This suggests looking at extensions $M$ of $L$ that are not normal over $K$. Does such an extension exist? Or is there a better example?

Comment: Seems to me that if you adjoin the sixth root of $t$, you should get an extension that's neither separable nor normal.

Comment: So we need to show x^6 - t is irreducible over K and that it doesn't split in K( t^(1/6) ) ? I tried to show this and didn't have any luck. Feel like I might be missing something obvious...

Comment: Show the extension doesn't contain $\rho t^{1/6}$, where $\rho^3=1\ne\rho$, and that will show the extension is not normal. Show that $x^6-t$ has multiple roots in a splitting field, and that will show the extension is not separable.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478135/give-3-examples-of-a-field-extensions-which-are-neither-normal-nor-separable also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232609/what-is-a-good-way-to-find-an-algebraic-field-extension-that-is-not-separable-an also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242542/example-of-an-non-normal-inseparable-field-extension

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand: why does showing the extension doesn't contain ρt^1/6, ρ^3=1≠ρ give us that it isn't normal? (I am self studying this material so I thank you for your patience). Are you saying roots of x^3 -t^.5 must be of this form? (If so, why is that?) I understand why the extension is not separable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for $\rho$ to be a primitive **6th** root of unity. $x^3-\sqrt t$ has degree 3, so at most 3 distinct roots in a splitting field, and $t^{1/6},\rho^2t^{1/6},\rho^4t^{1/6}$ are roots, so they are the roots.

Comment: Isn't the existence of a primitive 6th root of unity in an extension field impossible since K has characteristic 2, and 2 divides 6?

Comment: You have a good point. So maybe I meant a cube root of unity after all. Let $\rho^3=1\ne\rho$, then $t^{1/6},\rho t^{1/6},\rho^2t^{1/6}$ are the zeros of $x^3-\sqrt t$ in a splitting field.

Comment: Ok I see how that gives the result; so we need to show no primitive cube root of unity in K. If there was, then x^3 -1 = (x-1)(x-ρ)(x-ρ2), and this implies ρ(ρ+1)=1 i.e. ρ^2+ρ+1=0. So we want to show x^2 +x +1 is irreducible over K? I haven't been able to show this next step.

Comment: $K$ is a purely transcendental extension of $F_2$. Have you looked at any of the other questions I've linked? I think at least one of them explores this in some detail.

Comment: Are we OK now??

Comment: Hi, thank you for your continued interest. I did look at those other links, but I'm afraid they didn't address  the queries I had. I am stuck on showing K cannot have a primitive cube root of unity, as per your hint.  So K/F2 is transcendental, but L/K is algebraic since it is finite right?

Comment: That's right. Or, L/K is algebraic because you get L from K by adjoining an element that's algebraic over K.